# What's the password of the user which postgres generates matches os username?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres.

Postgres will generate two user when install it, one is 'postgres', the other matches your os username.

[Getting Started with PostgreSQL on Mac OSX #3-configuring-postgres](https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb#3-configuring-postgres):

> We see the Postgres user I mentioned, but what is that other user, engineerapart? This is one of the things Postgres does to make your life easier when you first install it...So when Postgres is installed, it automatically creates a database user that matches your username, so that you can get started right away.

But what's the password of the user that matches the os username?

My os username is 'zhouhancheng', and I often stuck with the error:

```sh
failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "zhouhancheng"
```

macos: 10.13
postgresql: 11.2

Comment: Side remark: it is not PostgreSQL that does that, this must be a whim of the packager, became that is different from any other PostgreSQL installation procedure I have seen.

Comment: I am uninstalling the current one, and try others. Thank you!

Comment: I install PostgreSQL by `brew install postgresql`, and only 11.2 works with macOS10.13, which give me the unnecessary user.

Comment: You can always become OS user `postgres`, connect as database user `postgres` and drop that user.

Comment: `DROP USER zhouhancheng`, I drop it, but when I type `psql` in command line, it still requires `Password for user zhouhancheng:`

Comment: PostgreSQL uses your operating system user name as default database user name. Use the option `-U postgres` or set the environment valiable `PGUSER` to `postgres`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I can solve the detailed problem. But 'what's the password of the user which postgres generates matches os username?', this question still need someone to answer.

Comment: Yes, but that someone is not me. I do not use Mac...

Answer (score 0):

As of version 10.6, PostgreSQL doesn't create password for os username by default.
Check your [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and allow passwordless access.
You can allow passwordless access from localhost with the following setting.

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Alternatively, when you initialize your database cluster with [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-initdb.html), you can specify password for os username.

```
-W
--pwprompt
Makes initdb prompt for a password to give the database superuser. If you don't plan on using password authentication, this is not important. Otherwise you won't be able to use password authentication until you have a password set up.
```

(I think `initdb` is executed by brew in your case though)

Comment: If you're using different version, still you can edit pg_hba.conf. `trust` in pg_hba.conf means you don't need password to login.